# Is there a way to do the following type of data manipulation in R?

Tags: r

[Here is the type of transformation I am trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPL3O.png)

Comment: Yes, `dplyr::pivot_longer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(123, 127), 
  first_name = c("john", "andrew"), 
  last_name = c("smith", "jones"), 
  orange_price = c(2.4, 3.2), 
  apple_price = c(2, 1), 
  kiwi_price = c(1.25, 0.75) 
) 


df %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "fruit", 
               values_to = "price", 
               cols = c(orange_price, apple_price, kiwi_price))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id first_name last_name fruit        price
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1   123 john       smith     orange_price  2.4 
#> 2   123 john       smith     apple_price   2   
#> 3   123 john       smith     kiwi_price    1.25
#> 4   127 andrew     jones     orange_price  3.2 
#> 5   127 andrew     jones     apple_price   1   
#> 6   127 andrew     jones     kiwi_price    0.75
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>